# HTML/CSS Hover Flip Visibility Issue with iOS devices

Tags: html, ios, css

The issue occurs only on iOS devices when viewing the image on the website.  When you tap the image, the image is supposed to flip over and reveal the back.  This works successfully in Windows(IE, Chrome,Firefox) and Android, but not iOS.  On iOS, the front image shows along with part of the back image.  When the image flips, the front image is still on top.  I have attached the HTML/CSS as well as screenshots of what I am seeing.  Any help will be greatly appreciated.

```css
<style>

.flip-container {
 perspective: 1000px;
}
 
 .flip-container:hover .flipper, .flip-container.hover .flipper {
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
 }

.flip-container, .front, .back {
 width: auto;
 height: auto;
}


.flipper {
 transition: 0.6s;
 transform-style: preserve-3d;

 position: relative;
}
.front, .back{
 backface-visibility: hidden;
  
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
}


.front {
 z-index: 2;
 width: 100%;
 height: auto;
 
 
 /* for firefox 31 */
 transform: rotateY(0deg);
 
}


.back {
 
 width: 100%;
 height: auto;
 
 transform: rotateY(180deg);
}
</style>
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<div class="flip-container" ontouchstart="this.classList.toggle('hover');">
 <div class="flipper">
  <div class="front">
   <!-- front content -->
   <img src="https://problemdescription.000webhostapp.com/front.png" width=90% border="0" alt="Null">
  </div>
  <div class="back">
   <!-- back content -->
   <img src="https://problemdescription.000webhostapp.com/back.png" width=90% border="0" alt="Null">
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
<body>
<div id="myModal" class="modal">
</html>
```

[image: Front Image View iOS]

[image: Back Image View iOS]

Answer (score 0):

```
.front, .back{
-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
backface-visibility: hidden;
position: absolute;
top: 0;
left: 0;
```

}

just add " -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden; "